# Purview API to show the contact names

Tags: azure-purview

I am only getting the Ids of contacts, owners, createdby and updatedby fields. Which API to use to get the corresponding names?

"contacts":{"Expert": [{"id": "aa874e20-85bd-4e63-a11d-ce715e2a85bb"}],"Steward": [{"id":aa874e20-85bd-4e63-a11d-ce715e2a85bb"}]}

Answer (score 0):

> i am only getting the Ids of contacts, owners, createdby and updatedby
> fields. Which API to use to get the corresponding names?

*Thank you @*Sindhuja Laxmipuram* posting your suggestion here as community wiki to beneficial for other community members for similar issue*.

> *You can use the below command to list the contact or owner name for*
> *the above*.
>
> ```
>  GET {Endpoint}/catalog/api/atlas/v2/entity/guid/{guid}?minExtInfo={minExtInfo}&ignoreRelationships={ignoreRelationships}
> ```

For more information please refer this **SO THREAD** | [***How to use REST API to extract role assignment information from a Azure Purview account***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71790867/how-to-use-rest-api-to-extract-role-assignment-information-from-a-azure-purview) .

Answer (score 0):

The API you actually need is a different one, called Microsoft Graph.

You can try it here by logging in with your company email:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

The following request will return a company email by using this 'id' field:

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/identities](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bid%7D/identities)

Then, you can see the full information of this user using their email:

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-mail}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buser-mail%7D)